# Using Chrome cast with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avplayer, chromecast, google-cast

I'm working on iOS app, and to play videos i'm using **AVPlayer**.

I need to add **chrome-cast support** with my player, but i'm not sure how i can do that or even if it's possible or not. 
i found a pod [google-cast-sdk](https://cocoapods.org/pods/google-cast-sdk), i guess it'll work.

How can i add chrome cast support in my iOS application with AVPlayer and will i have to do any encoding/decoding of videos?

Comment: There is plenty of documentation here: https://developers.google.com/cast/

Comment: @Fayza Did you get any solution for that ?

Comment: @mitulmarsonia, not yet.. i didn't spend much time on it.

Comment: @Fyza Thanks for replay.